# How to create communication with node.js server to client browser about monsters(object)

Tags: javascript, browser-based-games, node.js

First hello and sorry for my English, and now about my problem.
I create `node.js` server that communicates with the browser-client for player position, life, def, etc ... with `sockets.io`. And my question is how can i do and communication between server and client about this monster(bot) object?
[image: A small example of what I mean]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why won't the strategies for bi-directional communication you're already using for the player data work for the monster data?

Comment: Yes but whether it is right to make the communication between server and client about monsters(AI) with sockets.

Comment: Why would it be not right? Help us understand what specific problem you've found.

Comment: Stop thinking in terms of "right" and "wrong" and just focus on making things work for now. Then once you identify actual problems, come back and present them. Also, this is a very open-ended question and those are not a good fit for this site.